# App crashing on remote pushes with BKProcessAssertion

Tags: ios, background, google-analytics

I integrated the latest version of Google Analytics SDK. I use silent notifications in my app.
So I need a little time for background tasks(about 30 seconds).
I see many crashes connected with permitted time.

```
My App[3114] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x15699c00> identifier: Background Content Fetching (15) process: MyApp [3114] permittedBackgroundDuration: 30.000000 reason: backgroundContentFetching owner   
    pid:3101 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownUI  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}
```

I see tha app is crashing with the following stack on [GAI threadMain]:

```
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b47ca58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b47c854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3074c896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3074afbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x306b5f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x306b5cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x310a81e6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x310f909c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   MyApp                           0x0016df5c +[GAI threadMain:] + 60
9   Foundation                      0x3116aa5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b4f8916 _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b4f8886 _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b4f6aa0 thread_start + 4
```

I think that crash is connected with Google Analytics, I tried switch off Google Analytics on remote push like this:

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(BackgroundFetchResultBlock)completionHandler {
  ...
  [GAI sharedInstance].optOut = YES;
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: Thread 2 looks like it is just waiting to receive an event to process. Is there a "highlighted thread" in the crash log?

Comment: @Romula Did you ever resolve this? We're seeing this now, and we've redone our backgrounding, but still being snakebitten by GA

Answer (score 0):

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681355/34820).  In short, the problem is that your background task ran longer than the permitted amount of time.  The allowed background time was shortened significantly since iOS6; you may have to revisit your design and make adjustments.